# Showing $H=\langle a,b|a^2=b^3=1,(ab)^n=(ab^{-1}ab)^k\rangle$.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

> Let $G=\langle a,b|a^2=b^3=1,(ab)^n=(ab^{-1}ab)^k \rangle$. Prove that $G$ can be generated with $ab$ and $ab^{-1}ab$. And from there, $\langle(ab)^n\rangle\subset Z(G)$.

Problem wants $H=\langle ab,ab^{-1}ab \rangle$ to be $G$. Clearly, $H\leqslant G$ and after doing some handy calculation which takes time I've got:

> 1. $ab^{-1}=(ab^{-1}ab)(ab)^{-1}\in H$
> 2. $b=b^{-2}=(ab)^{-1}ab^{-1}\in H$
> 3. $a=(ab)b^{-1}\in H$

So $G\leqslant H$ and therefore $G=H=\langle ab,ab^{-1}ab\rangle$.

For the second part, I should prove that $N=\langle(ab)^n\rangle\leqslant Z(G)$.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: It is clear that $(ab)^n$ commutes with $ab$; since you proved that $G=H$, $G$ is generated by $ab$ and by $ab^{-1}ab$, so to show that $(ab)^n$ is in $Z(G)$ you are left with showing that $(ab)^n$ also commutes with $ab^{-1}ab$. Can you do that?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Oh yes. I see what you wanted. (ab)^n(ab)=(ab)(ab)^n is clear to me now. Thanks Mariano. I am doing the second.

Comment: but...$(ab)^n = (ab^{-1}ab)^k$ which clearly commutes with $ab^{-1}ab$

Comment: @DavidWheeler: I was on a wrong road. Thanks. Now it is obvious. I neglected (ab)^n=(ab^-1ab)^k. Thanks.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh: My dear brother, in that time I was working on some problems including presentation of groups. I think this problem had some defects in the body, so it was left unsolved here. Eltemase 2a daram. ;-)

Comment: @BabakSorouh, Thanks. "Presentation of groups". Finding Forms of Algebraic objects is always amusing and nice.

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered in the comments. However so that this question does not remain listed as unanswered forever, I will provide a solution. I will also give the details for the first part of the question.

**Part 1 Show $G= \langle ab, ab^{-1}ab  \rangle$**

Let $H=\langle ab, ab^{-1}ab \rangle $. It is clear that $ H \leq G$. We will show that $G \leq H$ by showing that $a$ and $b$ are in $H$.

We make the following observations which we will use in the argument:

1) $ (ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1} \in H $

2) $ a^{-1}=a $

3) $ b^{-2}=b $

Then $(ab^{-1}ab)(ab)^{-1}=ab^{-1} \in H$. Thus $ab^{-1} \cdot b^{-1}a^{-1} = ab^{-2}a = aba \in H$. Hence $(ab)^{-1} \cdot (aba) = a \in H$. Thus we have that $a \in H$ and then multiplying $ab$ with $a^{-1}$ on the left gives that also $b$ is in $H$. Hence $ G \leq H$ and we now can conclude $G=H$.

**Part 2 Show $ \langle (ab)^{n} \rangle \leq Z(G)$**

Since $G = \langle ab, ab^{-1}ab \rangle$ we will try to show $ab$ and $ab^{-1}ab$ commute with $(ab)^{n}$. Of course it is clear that $(ab)$ does. 
Now consider $$(ab^{-1}ab)\cdot (ab)^{n} = ab^{-1}ab(ab^{-1}ab)^{k}$$ (using a relation given in the presentation for $G$ in the question).
$$=(ab^{-1}ab)^{k+1}=(ab^{-1}ab)^{k}ab^{-1}ab = (ab)^{n} \cdot ab^{-1}ab$$

Hence we see that $(ab)^{n}$ commutes with both of our generators of $G$ and thus $ \langle (ab)^{n} \rangle $ is central.